# Which one is the best for this exercise and why

Tags: sentence-meaning

[image: exercise]
We should answer “Yes” first to the question “May/Can I help you?”, right? So I think the answer is B. Am I right?

Comment: In the context of asking someone why they are in some shop, "What do you buy?" is not grammatical. It should be "What do you want to buy?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

B is correct.  C is incorrect.  However, A is an interesting case.

As an exchange, the following is actually quite common:

> "Can I help you?"
>   "I want a pair of shoes for my son"

Syntactically, the answer given doesn't match the question, but *idiomatically*, "Can I help you?" is often interpreted as "**How** can I help you?".

That being said, for a simple multiple-choice exercise such as this one, your reasoning is correct and you should choose B. If you were actually using any of these in real conversation, though, you should be aware that "what do you want" is quite strongly associated with a tone of hostile dismissal, and another phrasing would often be better-received.

Comment: Given just the 3 choices as presented, the only credible one is B (A is an *introductory* utterance, not suitable as a reply to the preceding utterance). But *What do you want?* has such strong associations with "hostile dismissal" in other contexts that I'm sure the vast majority of sales assistants wouldn't use it. They'd more likely say something like *What [particular style] **are you looking for**?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers I read the question as "to which of these would "I want a pair of shoes for my son be an appropriate response" - notice the underscored space is on the *first* line, so the introductory utterance thing isn't really relevant. The point about the implied tone of "what do you want?", though, is a good one, and I shall edit in something to that effect.

Comment: oic - yes, of course you're right! I'd completely "reversed" the context. Still, *some* good came out of my comment! :)

Comment: (So on balance I'd say that although B is a "logically correct" answer, in the real world anyone who habitually initiated interactions with potential customers by saying ***What do you want**?* probably wouldn't earn much sales commission! :)

Comment: If we're allowed to discuss *idiomatic* conversation (since you bring it up in your answer), C would also be a valid question. I would assume it would be asked by somebody who didn't speak English as their first language. But the answer would be perfectly valid for that question. (I hate all tests of this type.)

Comment: @JasonBassford I hate them, too.